# how to record anything from soundcards?

Tags: delphi, wav, multimedia, audio, directsound

i would like to record any sounds produced in my soundcard. please help, where i can get a freeware component or commercial(trial). delphi7/2009

Answer (score 0):

I have very good experience with the [BASS](http://www.un4seen.com/bass.htm) audio library API.

[Here is a forum thread with C# example](http://www.un4seen.com/forum/?topic=6074.0), but since the BASS API is procedural and there is a good Delphi API interface, it translates pretty OK.

--jeroen

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matthew_van_eerde/archive/2008/12/16/sample-wasapi-loopback-capture-record-what-you-hear.aspx might help

Answer (score 0):

try http://sourceforge.net/projects/delphiasiovst/. there is a component to communicate with the ASIO driver. It's extremely easy to use, far more than DX or Windows audio.